# Swift: function overload resolution via closure parameter?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift, generics

I am trying to solve a separate problem related to parsing JSON.  In the process, I ran afoul of the Swift compiler, as I expected it to use closure template arguments to select a function overload for optional types.

I haven't seen anything explicit in their documentation on this topic, but is it not the expectation that all else equal, swiftc will use arguments of a closure parameter in a generic function to select the correct overload?

Here is the simplest sample that I could come up with:

```
import Foundation

let os:NSString = "foo!"
let d:[String:AnyObject] = ["a": os]

struct Model {
    var opt:String?
    var basic:String = ""
}


func read<T>(source:AnyObject?, set:T -> ()) {
    if let t:T = source as? T {
        println("basic: read type: \(T.self) from value \(source)")
    }
    else {
        println("failed to read basic type \(T.self) from value \(source)")
    }
}


func read<T>(source:AnyObject?, set:T? -> ()) {

    assert(false, "this is not called")

    if let t:T? = source as? T? {
        println("optional: read optional type: \(T.self) from value \(source)")
    }
    else {
        println("failed to read optional type \(T.self) from value \(source)")
    }
}


var m = Model()
println(m)
let raw: AnyObject? = d["a"]

struct Property<T> {
    typealias V = T
    var get:() -> T
    var set:T -> ()

    func doRead(d:[String:AnyObject]) {
        read(d["a"], set)
    }
}

let b = Property(get: { m.basic }, set: { v in m.basic = v })
b.doRead(d)

let o = Property(get: { m.opt }, set: { v in m.opt = v })
o.doRead(d)
```

Per the comment inline, I expected the second overload to be used for optional types, but it is not.  Am I missing something?

**Edit**

Note that the compiler is inferring the optional / non optional type from the property construct - it knows that the closure takes a optional, it just doesn't select the overload.  I have restored some of my original logging code above, and the output is:

> basic: read type: Swift.String from value Optional(foo!)
>
> failed to read basic type Swift.Optional from value Optional(foo!)

Answer (score 1):

From my usage of Swift, I see that the compiler prefers non-optionals over optionals. The operation:

`let o = Property(set: { v in m.opt = v })`

Is legal even when `v` is a non-optional, and therefore the compiler assumes as such.

This is a good question, and I assume a lot of other questions like this will be answered soon  when Swift is made open-source.